# How can I search for user_name and password in table contains MILLIONS OF records as fast as possible?

Tags: bigdata

### Hi there

There is a question I was not lucky to find a solution till now, **What technique Facebook use to match username and password in millions of record in few seconds or less**, I need a simple *example* for this case. In my work users less than 300,000 records so using LINEAR search not a big problem but what I have to do if users become millions???

Comment: ok, let's start - do you have a database?

Comment: my DB not big as facebook it contains about 300,000 user, but what can I do if I have one like face-book db